# Update Statement in Oracle SQL giving error as "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one SQL query which when running giving below error.

```
SQ Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

Below is the query which I am running. It checks for certain column and then only update a static value in column.
**SQL Statement:**

```
UPDATE(
SELECT UMR.*, RMINV.*
 FROM UNMATCHED_RAW_TABLE UMR
 INNER JOIN RMINV_RAWDATA_TEST RMINV
 ON UMR.PHONE_NUMBER = RMINV.ITEM_IDCIRCUITWTN
 WHERE UMR.CARRIER='ABCD'
 AND RMINV.account_num='12345'
 AND (RMINV.CC_CODE IS NULL OR RMINV.DEPARTMENT IS NULL)
)
SET UMR.UNMATCHED_REASONS = 'Missing Department'
```

Let me know if anything I am doing wrong here.

I have tried updating SQL as above but not working for me. I want to update Missing department only for the results comes from select query.

[Sample Data for both the table used in query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A8Df.png)

Comment: You try to update the result of a select, which is not a persisted table. That will not work. What you are trying to do? And how is this question related to python

Comment: So as asked in question I want to update all the records which comes from that select query only with a static hardcoded value, and the value which I am updating is static so its not dependent on any other table. How to do, that is what I asked. 
And about Python once I am able to run this scenario in SQL developer directly, then I'll put into my Python code.

Comment: Please share sample data

Comment: You're trying update `UNMATCHED_RAW_TABLE` but join with `RMINV_RAWDATA_TEST` might return more than one row. Try  to rewrite the UPDATE using `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can update a table based on a view. That view will have to result in one row per update table row, so the DBMS knows which row to look at for the update.

With your update statement the DBMS is telling you that the query is not guaranteed to produce one result row per UMR row. (And I am a bit surprised by the syntax; I don't think that the alias UMR is known outside the query, so `SET umr.unmatched_reasons = ...` must result in an error anyway.)

After all, you don't need a join here at all, because all you want to do is to update a table with a constant where a certain condition is met. So write an update statement on the table providing the appropriate `WHERE` clause. Use `EXISTS` or `IN` to lookup data in another table.

```
UPDATE unmatched_raw_table umr
SET unmatched_reasons = 'Missing Department'
WHERE carrier = 'ABCD'
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT null
  FROM rminv_rawdata_test rminv
  WHERE rminv.item_idcircuitwtn = umr.phone_number
  AND rminv.account_num = 12345
  AND (rminv.cc_code IS NULL OR rminv.department IS NULL) 
);
```

This is your update statement transformed into a plain table update. Check the conditions. Are these the conditions when you want to update the table? If not, amend them according to your needs.

Comment: Hi @thorsten-kettnern , it worked for me. I understood your point about table based on a view. Thanks for the help.